# Replacing specific values in numpy 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array like so:

```
[['a', '(junk, b)', '(junk, c)'],
 ['d', '(junk, e)', '(junk, f)'],
 ['g', '(junk, h)', '(junk, i)']]
```

As you can see some of the values have a parenthesis around them, I'd like to remove these extra values such that my new array is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['d', 'e', 'f'],
 ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

I have a regex to get the match group of the data I want to capture but is there a clean way within numpy to apply a regex to certain values at certain positions and return my new array with the unwanted values replaced?

Comment: For all practical purposes you have a nested list of lists.  Making it an object array, especially for operations like this, doesn't add much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to strip the items with `str.strip()` method :

```
>>> np.array([[x.strip('()') for x in i] for i in l])
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Based on your edit if you have extra words in your array you can use regex to match the single characters 
:

```
>>> l=[['a', '(junk, b)', '(junk, c)'],
...  ['d', '(junk, e)', '(junk, f)'],
...  ['g', '(junk, h)', '(junk, i)']]
>>> 
>>> np.array([[re.search(r'\b[a-z]\b',x).group() for x in i] for i in l])
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>>
```

Comment: This works, however I've edited my post to be a more accurate representation of the data, instead of applying strip I need to apply a regex that captures the desired data, would it be possible to capture the data that I want and ignore the rest of the data that's already formatted properly?